# how to get list of all projects by project category - Jira rest api

Tags: rest, jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to get list of all projects under projectCategory.
Currently,
**jira.domain.com/rest/2/project** - gives the list of all the projects in the organization.

**jira.domain.com/rest/2/projectCategory** -gives only the projectCategory name, id, description.

***Question:***

Is there a rest api to get all the projects under the projectCategory?

Answer (score 0):

The `jira.domain.com/rest/2/project` endpoint returns the value of the projectCategory in the JSON response. Use that returned value to filter your results.